# jQuery-not in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write the following jQuery-not…

```
$(".hover").not(".selected");
```

… in pure JavaScript?

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use jQuery or some other framework?

Comment: because of the performance … we use raphael already

Comment: Realize that jQuery is fairly well optimized, whatever code you write is most likely not going to be more efficient.

Comment: Also jQuery has been beaten upon, is cross-browser and what ever you gain in performance you will lose in maintainance. I also use Raphael with jQuery with no problems.  The slowest part is Raphael rendering I find...

Comment: @Zack: Not really. jQuery is a general purpose library for creating and acting on collections of DOM elements. For any specific task of creating a collection of DOM elements, an intelligently coded specific solution using no library will certainly be faster.

Comment: @Tim: All things equal, an intelligently coded specific solution will be at least as fast, as that's all jQuery is, beyond some sort of caching (which it doesn't do), there's no way it could be faster.  Yet using jQuery makes it much easier to, for example, apply your selector to only a single DOM element.  While it's definitely possible to do this manually, it's easy to overlook.  Unless you have a _very_ good reason, avoiding jQuery (assuming you're already using it on the page) amounts to premature optimization.

Comment: @Zack: I don't disagree with any of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
allItems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
goodItems = [];
for(i=0;i<allItems.length;i++){
    if(
        allItems[i].className && 
        (' '+allItems[i].className.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')+' ').indexOf(' '+'hover'+' ') != -1 && 
        (' '+allItems[i].className.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')+' ').indexOf(' '+'selected'+' ') == -1
    )
        goodItems.push(allItems[i]);
}
```

If you need these kind of class selections often you should consider saving them as functions or even replicating some of the jQuery behaviour to be able to do stuff like `$(".hover").not(".selected");`

Comment: `indexOf()` on the  is not a good test for whether an element has a particular class and will yield false positives. For example, an element with `class="foo_hover_bar"` will get matched by this code.

Comment: There's still a problem: this won't work in IE < 9, in which Arrays don't have an `indexOf()` method.

Answer (score 4):

The following will work. It could be optimized by using a native browser implementation of `getElementsByClassName()` where present to filter the list to just elements with the "hover" class.

```
function hasClass(el, cssClass) {
    return el.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + cssClass + "(\\s|$)").test(el.className);
}

var matchingElements = [];
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = allElements.length, el; i < len; ++i) {
    el = allElements[i];
    if (hasClass(el, "hover") && !hasClass(el, "selected")) {
        matchingElements.push(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alin: That's OK though, because it's not splitting on the regex. It checks that the class is either at the start or immediately preceded by a whitespace character; what precedes that whitespace character (if present) is irrelevant. The logic for checking the end of the class is similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use following function to get elements by class name.

`excludeClass` is an optional parameter here, this function will still work if you only define the `includeClass` parameter.

```
function getElementsByClassName(includeClass, excludeClass) {
    var elements = []; var el = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var regexp1 = new RegExp("\\b" + includeClass + "\\b");
    var regexp2 = new RegExp("\\b" + (excludeClass ? excludeClass : "") + "\\b");
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (regexp1.test(el[i].className) && !regexp2.test(el[i].className)) { elements.push(el[i]); }
    }
    return elements;
}
```